# Using ArcPy to fetch Information from File Geodatabase

Tags: arcpy, shapefile

I am new to GIS.

I have a .gdb folder with data and I need to process that data to find educational institutions which are within say X Km of the Roads and within Y Km of any other educational institution.

I need to generate a shapefile with the resulting data.

Do I need to install ArcGIS to do this or is it possible to do this in ArcPy alone?

I am pretty OK with Python and I seek a Python Snippet.  I am not looking for full code but just an idea to get me started.

Answer (score 4):

Buffer your road and school layer by your X and Y search distance.  Then do a select by location to see what schools are selected from the road buffer.  To find what schools intersect each other yoiu could run the Intersect tool on the school buffer.  These tools are common among both open source and proprietary GIS programs.

Specifically, in ArcMap you could run these operations in ModelBuilder then export out the code to python.